# CSS Display letters horizontally and add space between words

Tags: html, css, frontend

I'm wanna make the letters of two words display vertically, from top to bottom and, to add a controllable space(a kind of padding-top) on the the last word.(See below image)

[image: letter-direction: vertically]

(In Photoshop, you obtain the above effect by pressing Shift + Enter after a letter.)

---

I obtained something close, but somebody might know a better solution.

My solution:

> ```
> <p>Stalk &nbsp; Me</p>
>
> <!-- &nbsp; is a HTML space entity -->
>
> p {
>     font-size      : 20px;
>     width          : 28px;       /* depends on font-size */
>     line-height    : 20px;       /* depends on font-size */
>     word-wrap      : break-word;
>     text-transform : uppercase;
>     text-align     : center; 
> }
> ```
>
> Live example: https://jsbin.com/sacimo/edit?html,css,output

---

Can somebody help me?

Thank you!

Comment: With your original css, try changing the font-size & line-height to percent. With the line-height at 100%. Then change the width to use 1em. This works on IE11. Not sure how it does on chrome, firefox, or opera.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [`text-orientation: upright`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation) and [`writing-mode: vertical-rl`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode). Add `-webkit-` and `-ms-` [`Browser vendor prefixes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix) if needed like this [`Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/wgewb5nr/6/).

```css
p {
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: upright;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Stalk Me</p>
```

Comment: Why don't you mention the browser support tables?

Comment: @Pangloss not sure why but there is nothing on http://caniuse.com/#search=text-orientation

Comment: @Pangloss, In a way, he did. He added hyperlinks which point to: developer.mozilla.org .
 
Here are the support tables provided by caniuse: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-writing-mode

Comment: @NenadVracar That is strange. The output seems to be buggy on Chrome here.

Comment: Just tested it on opera 34 and it wasn't working but then i added prefixes and it works https://jsfiddle.net/wgewb5nr/5/.

Comment: @NenadVracar Yep, the latest Chrome 48 just made it unprefix. But it still missing the whitespace between the words.

Comment: @Pangloss I just tested it on chrome v 48.0.2564.97 and it works.

Comment: @NenadVracar Not sure why it's missing the space here. Anyway I agree that it's probably the the only solution without editing the markup.

Comment: @NenadVracar I mean CSS, but that is a nice piece script :)